# How to close my openCentredWindow?

Tags: javascript

Step 1 : Below is my javascript for popup window.

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
    var myWindow;

    function openCenteredWindow(url) {
    var width = 780;
    var height = 215;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",status,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;
    myWindow = window.open(url, "subWind", windowFeatures);
    }
    //-->
    </SCRIPT>
```

Step 2 : Below is my form page display in my javascript pop up window.

```
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"><span class="style6">Menu Details</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF"><table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="17%" bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;<strong>Diet Menu Item</strong></td>
                <td width="26%" bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;<? echo $DIET_MENUITEM_ID;?></td>
                <td width="11%" bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;<strong>Serving Size</strong></td>
                <td width="27%" bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;<? echo $SERVING_SIZE;?></td>
                <td width="12%" bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;<strong>Enabled</strong></td>
                <td width="7%" bgcolor="#E8F2FF"><input name="ENABLED" type="checkbox" id="ENABLED" value="1" <? if($ENABLED==1){?>checked <? }?> /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;<strong>Cook Instructions</strong></td>
                <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#E8F2FF"><textarea name="COOK_INSTRUCTION" cols="50" rows="5" id="COOK_INSTRUCTION"><? echo $COOK_INSTRUCTION;?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF"><input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update"></td>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
                <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#E8F2FF">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"><span class="style6">&nbsp;<? echo $info;?></span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**Issue : How to autoclose the pop up window after I click submit button in step 2. Im having problem to autoclose the pop up window after clicking submit button**

Comment: Side note, for the love of god, use `<script type="text/javascript">` and every time you make ALL CAPS HTML tags, God slaughters a puppy very viciously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're inside of popup itself, you can simple call `window.close();` to close it. Where to put it depends on when you want to close it. For example if your want to close it after some server-side processing, you can add to server-side code something like:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>"
```

Comment: Where should I put echo script in my popup?